# Find all files and use the result in grep search pattern

Tags: bash, shell, grep, find

I found an example which uses a combination of find and xarg or exec to search a specific pattern from the result see link [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21033/how-can-i-grep-the-results-of-find-using-exec-and-still-output-to-a-file).

However I'd like to use the result of find command and use it as search pattern for grep. Something like command below but am not sure how to construct it.

```
find . -name "*.cgi" -printf '%f\n' | cut -d. -f1 | xarg grep 'find_result' *.html
```

Comment: @SatoKatsura thanks but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming GNU `grep`, and assuming your filenames don't have embedded newlines:

```
find . -name '*.cgi' -printf '%f\n' | cut -d. -f1 | sort -u | fgrep -f - *.html
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `xargs` here, you can just have `grep` read the pattern list from stdin:

with GNU find:

```
find . -name '*cgi' -printf '%f\n' | grep -f - *html
```

otherwise:

```
find . -name '*cgi' | cut -f2- -d/ | grep -f - *html
```

Comment: thanks Eric... this one works as well but I have to give the points to sato