# Finding number of lines using find command

Tags: command-line, find, wc

Consider the R source code repository found at https://cloud.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.4.4.tar.gz .  I unzipped the repository into a folder. Now, I wish to find out how many total lines are there in the directory.  So, I tried the following command:

```
find . -type f -exec wc -l {} \+
```

which yields 394968 but if I try the following command:

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} \+ | wc -l
```

it yields 1848857!

Why are these two seemingly similar operations of the `find` command producing such drastically different results?  And, what is the correct way to go about finding number of lines, preferably using command line utilities instead of scripting a small tool?

Comment: Did you get only one number back from the first command?

Comment: No, a list of lines for all the files.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first command you mention, `find . -type f -exec wc -l {} +`,
really says "run `wc -l` on as many files as possible, until all of
them have been processed". This can run `wc` multiple times!

On the other hand, `find . -type f -exec cat {} + | wc -l` can run
`cat` several times, but will only run `wc` once. (More in detail,
this is because in this case `cat` is called by `find`, which can and
does decide to run it however many times it wants, whereas the part
after the pipe character, `wc -l`, is beyond the reach of `find`, and
is therefore run by your shell, just once.)

You say that the first command "yields 394968", but it really does
not; on my system its output ends with:

```
(Many more lines elided...)
     23 ./po/Makefile.win
     64 ./po/README
      1 ./VERSION-NICK
     97 ./README
 258450 total
```

Yet, by adding `grep total`, one can see that `wc` was really run twice:

```
$ find . -type f -exec wc -l {} + | grep total
 1590407 total
 258450 total
```

And, indeed, 1590407 plus 258450 is 1848857, which agrees with the second command.

---

An explanation of why `wc` was run more than once
in the `find -exec wc +` version of the command
is vaguely hinted at by [the find man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

> `-exec command {} +`
>
> This  variant  of the `-exec` action runs the specified command on
>   the selected files, but the command line is built  by  appending
>   each  selected file name at the end;
>   the total number of invocations of the command
>   will  be  much  less  than  the  number  of
>   matched  files.   The command line is built in much the same way
>   that `xargs` builds its command lines.

Note how this says "much less than ..." rather than "only once". The
[documentation for xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) hints that its option `--max-chars` is set
automatically if not set by the user:

> `--max-chars=max-chars`
>   `-s max-chars`
>
> Use at most *`max-chars`* characters per command line, including the
>   command  and  initial-arguments and the terminating nulls at the
>   ends of the argument strings. 
>   The largest allowed value is system-dependent,
>   and  is  calculated as the argument length limit
>   for exec, less the size of your environment, less 2048 bytes  of
>   headroom.   If this value is more than 128KiB, 128Kib is used as
>   the default value; otherwise, the default value is the  maximum.

This limits how many filenames can be passed to a single call to `wc`,
explaining why, for large numbers of files, several calls to `wc` will
occur, each operating on a partition of the input.

Comment: Nitpick: `+` is not a special character. No need to escape it.

Comment: Follow up question: on a directory with fewer files, both commands output the same total (as `wc` is only called once). What enforces this limit on the number of arguments passed to `wc`?

Comment: follow-up answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196917/117549

Comment: and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21034/117549

Comment: Good point, Kusalananda; I will integrate this into the answer.

Comment: Thanks @dhag !  Very good explanation...especially about `wc` running multiple times.  It appears that in my case it runs two times with 1453889 and 394968 lines which still adds up to 1848857.

Comment: Just for reference: the command `find . -type f | xargs wc -l` also calls `wc -l` twice!  Apparently, this is discussed in the `-s` and `-n` options of `man xargs`.